# React MUI focusVisible ripple animation on hover

Tags: material-ui

I rather like the focus animation on buttons (e.g., when tabbing through them). I'd like to apply the same animation on hover as well.

It looks like this, but pulsating:

[image]

It looks like it adds a prefix-focusVisible class when focused, and it makes some modifications to an internal <span> in the button. It looks like ButtonBase has a ripple ref that it calls `pulsate()` on, which I think is what activates it.

Is there a clean way I can invoke this on hover for Buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Button props is `touchRippleRef`, which exposes a `pulsate()` function. I wrapped the `Button` component, and got the pulsing-ripple-animation on hover working:

```
function LinkButton(props: ButtonProps) {

  const touchRippleRef = useRef<TouchRippleActions>(null)

  return <Button 
    {...props}
    touchRippleRef={touchRippleRef}
    onMouseEnter={() => touchRippleRef.current?.pulsate()}
    onMouseLeave={() => touchRippleRef.current?.stop()}
  />
}
```

Works like a charm.